# Pandas sum() with character condition

Tags: python, pandas, string, cumsum

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>>variable    value
0  var1        0.25
1  var2        0.11
2  tt_var1     0.01
3  tt_var2     0.0004
4  tt_var3     0.07
5  bb_var5     0.102
6  var_3       0.45
7  bb_var74    0.23
```

I want to use cumsum() in order to sum the values in column "1", but only for specific variables: I want to sum all the variables that start with tt and all the variable that start with bb in my dataframe, so in the end i'll have the folowing table :

```
>>>variable    value
0  var1        0.25
1  var2        0.11
2  tt          *sum of all tt **
3  bb          *sum of all bb**
4  var_3       0.45
```

I know how to use cumsum but I haven't found any way to specify it to be only on specific rows that have something in common in one row (e.g the letters bb or tt).

**Is there any way to use cumsum() in this way?**

Comment: Shouldn't `5  bb_var74    0.23` be considered under **sum of all bb** @Reut?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want `cumsum` or `sum` for values with `tt` and `bb`?

Comment: @Vishnudev yes, I have fixed it, sorry

Comment: @Mayank Porwal I think you are right it should be the sum of all values and not cumsum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html),

```
grouper = df['variable'].replace({'tt_.*': 'tt', 'bb_.*': 'bb'}, regex=True)
df.groupby(grouper).sum().reset_index()
```

Output

```
  variable   value
0       bb  0.3320
1       tt  0.0804
2     var1  0.2500
3     var2  0.1100
4    var_3  0.4500
```